# different behaviour of input scanner and parse in android studio and netbeans

Tags: java, android, netbeans

I am reading the same pipe-delimited file using NetBeans (to test the basic code) and Android Studio (actual application) and getting different results.

Here is the offending code:

```
String URL = "http://.../CalendarUTF8(Dec2016).txt";

try {
  java.net.URL url = new java.net.URL(URL); 
  Scanner input = new Scanner(url.openStream());
  int i;
  for (i = 0; input.hasNext(); i++) {
    String temp = input.nextLine();
    eventCalendar[i] = temp.split("\\|",9);
  }
}
catch (java.io.IOException ex) {
  System.out.println("IO Errors");
}
```

Code works perfectly in NetBeans. Same file being read in Android Studio randomly breaks an input line in the middle, and then reads it as 2 lines. I checked the file and there is no hidden characters at the place where it gets split. If I write the parser myself, works fine as well.

Comment: could you plz post your file too? `Scanner s = new Scanner(input).useDelimiter("|");`  use this to set your delimiter to `|` because by default delimiter is `whitespace`.

Comment: `useDelimiter` receives `Pattern` object. Hence you should escape `|` symbol. So: `Scanner s = new Scanner(input).useDelimiter("\\|");`

Comment: You can use this URL to get the file: "http://nycjazzrecord.com/Calendar/CalendarUTF8(Dec2016).txt"

Comment: But, as I said, it does not happen all the time, only occasionally, and at the place where there is nothing strange. E.g. string "... 4th St ..." breaks as "... 4t" and "h St ...", Checked it in Notepad++ for special characters, and there are none.

Comment: Also, when you say "delimiter", do you mean delimiter within the string ("|") or delimiter for the end of the record/line (e.g. CR LF, etc.)? I don't think I have a problem with the former, split() works fine. It is nextLine() which gives me a problem. The easiest way to test would be to read the file and see how many records you got. If more than 967, then line breakage occurred. I guess, I can provide a better test program:

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is in using hasNext() in the header of for loop and using nextLine() in the body of for loop. When I replaced hasNext() with hasNextLine(), my record counts matched. Don't understand why, since hasNext() is supposed to look at something, not change, but it worked.